# How are dates formatted on Yahoo Finance?

Tags: date, yahoo-finance

I'm making a Python program to get stock data from Yahoo Finance. I want it to be able to get data from multiple stocks *at multiple dates.* The URL is like this: `https://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=GOOG&date=1423785600`, and I know how to change the stock sign, but how are the dates formatted? Is there a way to compute this or should I just brute-force it and look through all the options on the drop-down Dates menu?

Comment: That date 1423785600 looks like a Unix time stamp. i.e. The number of seconds since Thursday, 1 January 1970

Comment: `1423785600` is Fri 2015-02-13 00:00:00 UTC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be formatted as the total number of seconds since January 1st, 1970 00:00:00.000 UTC (the Unix Timestamp).

Answer (score 1):

That date 1423785600 looks like a Unix time stamp. i.e. The number of seconds since Thursday, 1 January 1970

Answer (score -3):

If you are working in Python staw away from having to download data from websites. There are better solutions incorporated in python once you get a hand on data. Try to make use of pandas and its Options property to download data in one line of code, rather then adjusting names of websites.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).